# Issue with connecting postgresql in django

Tags: python, django, linux, postgresql, psycopg2

i made a project on django. i work in virtualenv, i installed psycopg2-binary, tried to connect postgresql instead of sqlite3. rewrite code in settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'database',
        'USER': 'user',
        'PASSWORD': 'mypassword',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

and when enter python manage.py runserver, i get this

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...


    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "user"
connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "user"


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1016, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 953, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/user/Desktop/project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/Desktop/project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 136, in inner_run
    self.check_migrations()
  File "/home/user/Desktop/project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 574, in check_migrations
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
  File "/home/user/Desktop/project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 18, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "/home/user/Desktop/project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 58, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/home/user/Desktop/project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 235, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "/home/user/Desktop/project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 81, in applied_migrations
    if self.has_table():
  File "/home/user/Desktop/project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 57, in has_table
    with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
  File "/home/user/Desktop/project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/Desktop/project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 330, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "/home/user/Desktop/project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 306, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/home/user/Desktop/project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/Desktop/project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 288, in ensure_connection
    with self.wrap_database_errors:
  File "/home/user/Desktop/project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/user/Desktop/project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 289, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/home/user/Desktop/project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/Desktop/project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 270, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/home/user/Desktop/project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/Desktop/project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 275, in get_new_connection
    connection = self.Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/home/user/Desktop/project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "user"
connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "user"
```

how to solve this issue?

I tried to solve this problem in chatgpt, it did not help me. i hope you can help me with that

Comment: *'password authentication failed for user "user"'* It's rather obvious: you gave the wrong credentials.

Comment: check credentials on django settiings side and postgresql side, they must match

Comment: how to check and change credentials if it's needed?

Answer (score 0):

check in configuration I think you write wrong **(NAME or USER or PASSWORD)**

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'database', <------ check this
        'USER': 'user', <------ check this
        'PASSWORD': 'mypassword', <------ check this
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

1. in **NAME** you need to write **database name** which you created in pgAdmin.
2. in **USER** you need to write owner of database which you find **(right click on database > Properties > Owner)**
3. in **PASSWORD** you need to write login password of pgAdmin

Answer (score 0):

If you sure that PostgreSQL Database is successfully installed than You should install Pg Admin (I use Post bird, I'm using Linux Ubuntu)for PostgreSQL client database and try to login through one these clients, once you logged in to your Pg Admin than you can use those credentials to edit your settings.py